# C++ I have an array of my class and i want to accsess elements of it

Tags: c++, arrays, class

Im new to programming sorry if the terms im using are wrong.

I have to create a console app where the use can add, modify, print and delete food items.

I made a class for my food

```
class food{
private:
bool isBasic;
nmfvg MeatOrOther;
string name;
public:
food::food(){
        isBasic=true;
        MeatOrOther = NONE;
        name = "";
}

food::food(string _name,bool _isBasic, nmfvg _MeatOrOther){
isBasic=_isBasic;
MeatOrOther=_MeatOrOther;
name = _name;
}};
```

and im putting the food the user is making into an array of type food.

```
food foods[100];
food temp("food1",true,VEG); 
foods[0]=temp;
```

1-Is this the right way for me to store foods?
2-If it is how do i go about printing the name of foods[0]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a better practice, you can keep the food objects in a std::vector instead of array like:

```
std::vector<food> foods;
foods.push_back(temp("food1",true,VEG));
```

To print name member, you may need a get method as public:

```
std::string food::GetName()
{
   return name;
}
```

Then you can print the name by:

```
std::cout<<foods[0].GetName();
```

Comment: of course. Why function, that not modify object should not be const? Why we shouldn't use GetName() on const object?

Answer (score 1):

It's ok, but probably `vector` will be better.
You can print `name`, by adding `accessor` to name

```
class food {
//
public:
   string get_name() const { return name; }
};

std::cout << foods[0].get_name() << std::endl;
```

or by use some function/`operator <<` for output, or by making `name` public member and then simply use

```
std::cout << foods[0].name << std::endl;
```